# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'

Tags: python-3.x, vlc, attributeerror, libvlc

I want to use vlc in python but I always have that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "radio.py", line 3, in <module>
    media = vlc.MediaPlayer('annonce.mp4')
  File "C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 3310, in __new__
    o = instance.media_player_new()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'
```

And my code :

```
import vlc

media = vlc.MediaPlayer('annonce.mp4')
media.play()
```

My video is in my program file and I use Python 3.8.3.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the entire traceback?

Comment: Where are you instantiating `instance` in your code?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't find a lot of information on this module and I don't really know what is an instance

Comment: @DanielWalker done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the absolute barebones method to get this working:

```
import vlc
import time

playing = set([1,2,3,4])
media = vlc.MediaPlayer('/home/rolf/Brassic01.mp4')
media.play()
while media.get_state() in playing:
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

The instantiating of the vlc `instance` is performed for you, when using `MediaPlayer`.
You must loop while the instance is playing, thus we check the `state`.
If you are getting complaints about `no attribute` I would suggest that either you're missing a working version of `vlc` itself or there is a problem with your copy of `vlc.py`.

- Ensure that you can run `vlc` from the command line
- Get a current copy of `vlc.py` and place it in the same directory as your program

getting `vlc.py`:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings/

or

- https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated/3.0;h=7b5f65ac88f3ac7f81ee904676d70d8ca0a18ded;hb=HEAD

Comment: I changed vlc.py code (copy from link you gave me) and I copy it in my project folder but when I run your program, it only creates a folder named "__pycache__" and program ends without doing anything else...

Comment: What happens if, in that directory, you run `python vlc.py annonce.mp4`  ? It should play the video.

Comment: Plays the video

Comment: @RomainLB Then I would suggest that you open a python prompt on the command line and step through the code, line by line, by typing it in and see if you get any clues, as to what is wrong with your setup.

Comment: `import vlc media = vlc.MediaPlayer("C:\\Users\\Romain\\Desktop\\VLCTest\\annonce.mp4")
media.play()` I placed that in python prompt and it worked perfectly, i copy the same code in my IDE and it didn't worked... I really don't understand: no error, the code just starts and ends without doing anything else. Im' using Studio Code 1.46

Comment: @RomainLB Sorry, I have no clue. I've never used an IDE, it introduces another level of complication. Run the code, above, on the command line i.e. in C:\\Users\\Romain\\Desktop\\VLCTest\\ `python thecode.py`